# how to implement help action in qt

Tags: qt

I want to know how to implement help menu actions in Qt. When I click the HELP action, the RTF file should come up in a window or view.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the [Qt Help Framework](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qthelp-framework.html).